# Require selection from two groups of radio buttons before submitting MTurk assignment

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I am using the provided html template from Amazon MTurk, to test Audio Naturalness (https://requestersandbox.mturk.com/create/projects/new). In my experiment, each audio sample will have two sentences. The worker will need to select a rating for each of the two sentences before proceeding.

I've successfully modified the template so that there is only 1 audio sample, and two groups of radio buttons. However, I cannot omit the `Submit` button after the first group (see screenshot).
[image]

Here is the modified code. What should I omit or concatenate so there is only one `Submit` button after both groups of radio buttons? It seems from [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_HTMLQuestionArticle.html#ApiReference_HTMLQuestionArticle-crowd) that since there is only 1 `crowd-form` element, there should only be 1 "Submit" button.

```
<!-- You must include this JavaScript file -->
<script src="https://assets.crowd.aws/crowd-html-elements.js"></script>

<!-- You must include crowd-form so that your task successfully submit answers -->
<crowd-form answer-format="flatten-objects">

    <!-- The crowd-classifier element will create a tool for the Worker to select the 
          correct answer to your question -->
    <crowd-classifier 
        categories="['Excellent - Completely natural speech', 'Good - Mostly natural speech', 'Fair - Equally natural and unnatural speech', 'Poor - Mostly unnatural speech', 'Bad - Completely unnatural speech']"
        header="How natural (i.e. human-sounding) is the first voice sample?"
        name="audio-naturalness-1">
        
            <classification-target>
                <audio controls="" style="width: 100%">

                    <!-- Your audio file URLs will be substituted for the "audio_url" variable 
                          when you publish a batch with a CSV input file containing multiple 
                          audio file URLs -->
                    <source src="${audio_url}" type="audio/mp3" />

                </audio>
            
            </classification-target>
    </crowd-classifier>
    
    <crowd-classifier 
        categories="['Excellent - Completely natural speech', 'Good - Mostly natural speech', 'Fair - Equally natural and unnatural speech', 'Poor - Mostly unnatural speech', 'Bad - Completely unnatural speech']"
        header="How natural (i.e. human-sounding) is the second voice sample?"
        name="audio-naturalness-2">
        
            
    </crowd-classifier>
</crowd-form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if it is possible with classification element, but
the `crowd-radio-group` & `crowd-radio-button` should solve work for your purpose.

The documentation includes a bare-bones template for a single group. For multiple, I included a unique `name` attribute in each and ran it through the Requester Sandbox. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYPvV.png)

```
<crowd-radio-group name="S1">
<crowd-radio-button name="S1_1" value="Poor">Poor</crowd-radio-button>
...
<crowd-radio-button name="S1_5" value="Excellent">Excellent</crowd-radio-button>
</crowd-radio-group>


<crowd-radio-group name="S2">
<crowd-radio-button name="S2_1" value="Poor">Poor</crowd-radio-button>
...
<crowd-radio-button name="S2_5" value="Excellent">Excellent</crowd-radio-button>
</crowd-radio-group>
```

From there, the output should produce:

```
{
  "S1_1.Poor": false,
  "S1_2.Bad": false,
  "S1_3.Fair": false,
  "S1_4.Good": false,
  "S1_5.Excellent": true,
  "S2_1.Poor": false,
  "S2_2.Bad": false,
  "S2_3.Fair": false,
  "S2_4.Good": false,
  "S2_5.Excellent": true
}
```

I could not find anything for form validation, but here is a simple approach
to check and highlight a missing group. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O21tc.png)

```
function is_valid_group(rbg)
{
    'use strict';
    var radio_group=document.querySelector(`crowd-radio-group[name="${rbg}"`);
    var radios = radio_group.querySelectorAll(`crowd-radio-button[role="radio"]`);
    var valid_group = false;
    for (let i = 0, j = radios.length; i < j; i++)
    {
        valid_group = valid_group || radios[i].checked;
    }

    if (valid_group === false)
    {
        for (let i = 0, j = radios.length; i < j; i++)
        {
            radios[i].parentElement.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
        }
    }
    return valid_group;
}

window.onload = function()
{
    'use strict';
    document.querySelector(`crowd-form`).onsubmit = event =>
    {
        if (!is_valid_group("S1") || !is_valid_group("S2"))
        {
            alert("Please answer both questions");
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

You can always ditch the crowd-elements. The crowd-form may be necessary, but standard HTML elements seem to work fine. Here is an
example I was working with before I stumbled on the crowd-radio-group.
https://gitlab.com/snippets/2013533/raw